# get "ReferenceError: playwright is not defined" when using playwright.config.js

Tags: playwright

My very first day trying Playwright and I am having trouble using config. My steps:

1. init project and install

```
npm init
npm i -D @playwright/test --save
npx playwright install
```

2. create tests/foo.spec.js

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('basic test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
  const title = page.locator('.navbar__inner .navbar__title');
  await expect(title).toHaveText('Playwright');
});
```

3. run it

```
$ npx playwright test
  ✓  tests/foo.spec.js:3:1 › basic test (3s)
```

4. Create playwright.config.js

```
// @ts-check
const { devices } = require('@playwright/test');

/** @type {import('@playwright/test').PlaywrightTestConfig} */
const config = {
    use: {
        headless: false,
        viewport: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        video: 'on-first-retry',
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

5. run again and get error

```
$ npx playwright test
Using config at /Users/me/git/left/playwright/playwright.config.js
ReferenceError: playwright is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/git/left/playwright/playwright.config.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
...
(/Users/me/git/left/playwright/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/test/cli.js:80:7)
```

6. Thank you for helping. My env.

```
playwright@1.0.0 /Users/me/git/left/playwright
└── @playwright/test@1.15.0  

$ npm -v
7.18.1 

$ node -v
v16.4.2
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but its working for me as expected when following your steps. Can you repro it when you try it again?

Comment: @MaxSchmitt You are right. I must have had some errors in the config file while I was trying.  I cannot recall the file to see exactly what's wrong.  My question becomes invalid I wonder if there is a way to close.

Answer (score 0):

moving `expect`s out of the `evaluate` to the chained `then` solved the issue for me:

```
await page.evaluate(() => return val).then(val => expect(val).toBeDefined())
```